# xmodmap: Map numpad to one set of keycodes, Shift-numpad to some other set of keycodes, detected by Blender

Tags: xmodmap

I am able to map my numpad with, for example, an `~./Xmodmap` file like this:

```
keycode 87 = XF86Launch1
keycode 88 = XF86Launch2
keycode 89 = XF86Launch3
keycode 83 = XF86Launch4
keycode 84 = XF86Launch5
keycode 85 = XF86Launch6
keycode 79 = XF86Launch7
keycode 80 = XF86Launch8
keycode 81 = XF86Launch9
keycode 90 = XF86LaunchA
keycode 91 = XF86LaunchB
```

Of course, this means my numpad no longer enters numbers nor provides nav functions (Home, PgUp, etc.).  Up to now, I've been living with that, but now I am using an application (Blender) that has mapped many functions to the numpad.  I'm able to get by with an alternative `~/Xmodmap.numpad` file with contents like this:

```
keycode  79 = KP_Home KP_7 KP_Home KP_7
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode
keycode  83 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode  84 = KP_Begin KP_5 KP_Begin KP_5
keycode  85 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
keycode  86 = KP_Add XF86Next_VMode KP_Add XF86Next_VMode
keycode  87 = KP_End KP_1 KP_End KP_1
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode  89 = KP_Next KP_3 KP_Next KP_3
keycode  90 = KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
```

but switching between them is a hassle.  Can I just use xmodmap to have my numpad act like the first file normally, but act like the second file when I hold Shift?

When I use xev to inspect the keycodes, Shift-numpad doesn't give different keycodes than normal numpad, it just sends a keycode for the Shift key separately from the numpad key.

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184888/xmodmap-shift-keycode-to-produce-keysym) suggests that one can provide Shift alternatives with more entries, space separated.  But Blender doesn't seem to recognize the keystrokes.

Comment: I can see KP_1, KP_2, etc. taking effect elsewhere, but I guess Blender is detecting the Shift key by itself, and therefore ignoring my attempts to fool it...